# Does LinqToTwitter support Replay and/or Backfill filtering?

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

Does LinqToTwitter support Replay and/or Backfill filtering in v4.1, I can't work out how to do it when using StreamingType.Filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Replay or Backfill, I'm assuming you mean past tweets. No, the Twitter API streams only provide real-time tweets. To get past tweets, you need to use the REST API or Gnip.